# Printing data retrieved from SQLite3 database with C++ the same way as in command line

Tags: c++, sqlite

as said in the title, I'm writing a program in C++ and I'd like to know if it is possible to print the table the same way as it'd look like when I type the query in command line.

Example:

```
sqlite> select * from departments;
DepartmentId  DepartmentName
------------  --------------
1             KTI
2             KAM
3             KSI
4             KCN
```

I do know about sqlite3_exec(), but as I understand it, I would have to draw the table myself. Is there any ways to make sqlite3 print the output itself?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: I would think you'll need to work with `printf` to make it pretty-print like that.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the string concatenation operator `||` to combine multiple columns into a single string in your query. This can be useful when you need a quick and dirty way to comma-separated values from your database, however, you won't be able to get the type of formatting you are looking for without writing your own code.

ex
`SELECT lastName || ', ' || lastName FROM PEOPLE;`

gives you

```
"Doe, John"
"Buttons, Benjamin"
```

Fortunately, the CLI is [open source](https://sqlite.org/src/file?udc=1&ln=on&ci=tip&name=src%2Fshell.c.in) and you can look at how it implements the output formatting to give you some idea how to implement it yourself. The `exec_prepared_stmt` and `shell_callback` functions seem to be where all the good stuff is at.